# Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$. Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x)\sin(nx)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, fourier-analysis

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$. Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x)\sin(nx)\,dx$.

$f$ is continuously differentiable.

I'm told this can be done using basic calculus. It's difficult for me to see where I should begin. I'd like some hints.

Comment: This (classical) result goes by the name of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. Here is a nice exposition:.


  [1]: http://kurser.math.su.se/file.php/812/Riemann-Lebesgue-Vretblad.pdf

Comment: Without some conditions on $\,f\,$ it's impossible to say anything about that integral. In fact, it may even be that $\,f(x)\sin nx\,$ isn't even integrable there...

Comment: My mistake. I was originally asked this question with the premise that $f$ was continuously differentiable.

Comment: @user83210 Then you should edit your question.

Comment: [See here for a proof using step functions and Riemann's condition for integrability](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387060/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-limits-ab-sin-leftnt-righ/387089#387089)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function $f$ is continuous the limit is $0$. Just notice that $f$ is uniformly continuous, and that on every small interval $[2k\pi/n,(2k+2)\pi/n]$ the function $sin(nx)$ has integral $0$ while $f$ is close to a constant. So the integral will be close to $0$.

In general consider the piecewise constant function obtained replacing $f$ with its mean value on every such small intervals... and prove that the integral of the difference (between $f$ and the piecewise constant function) goes to zero. In practice you want to find $f_n$ such that 
$$
  \left\vert \int_a^b f(x) \sin(nx)\right\vert \le \left\vert \int_a^b (f(x)-f_n(x)) \sin(nx)\right\vert + \left\vert \int_a^b f_n(x) \sin(nx)\right\vert = \int_a^b \lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\rvert < \varepsilon.
$$

Comment: The last sentence is false; the limit is always zero even if $f$ is only in $L^1$.

Comment: Right... I removed that sentence.

Comment: See precise argument in the document cited above.

Comment: mStudent's comment about the Riemann-Lebesque lemma is easier for me to understand than the second paragraph of your post. Could you clarify? I'm interested in using methods that don't involve analysis. Because, well, this is a high school math club. But I'm not smart enough to comprehend what the second part of your answer accomplishes.

Answer (score 1):

This (classical) result goes by the name of **Riemann-Lebesgue lemma**. In the comment above I cited an exposition of proof for $f$ that is Riemann integrable. Here I consider the general case of $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R^d})$ and its Fourier transform
$$\widehat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R^d}} f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi} dx. $$
The  claim is that $\widehat{f}(\xi)\rightarrow 0$ as $|\xi|\rightarrow\infty$.

Let $\xi' = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\xi}{|\xi|^2}$ so that $|\xi'|\rightarrow 0$ as $|\xi|\rightarrow\infty$. Next, by translation invariance of the integral

\begin{align}
\widehat{f}(\xi) &= \int_{\mathbb{R^d}} f(x-\xi')e^{-2\pi i(x-\xi')\xi} dx\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R^d}} f(x-\xi')e^{-2\pi ix\xi} e^{2\pi i\xi'\xi} dx
=\int_{\mathbb{R^d}} -f(x-\xi')e^{-2\pi ix\xi}  dx
\end{align}
since $e^{2\pi i\xi'\xi} = e^{\pi i} =-1$. We can now write
\begin{align}
\widehat{f}(\xi) &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R^d}} [f(x)-f(x-\xi')]e^{-2\pi i(x-\xi')\xi} dx
\end{align}
so that $|
\widehat{f}(\xi)|\le ||f-f_{\xi'}||_{L^1}$ where $f_{\xi'}(x)=f(x-\xi')$ is the translation of $f$ by $\xi'$. We are done because translations are continuous with respect to the norm. Let's make this statement precise.

For $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R^d})$, $||f-f_{h}||_{L^1}\rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$. We use the fact that continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^1$. Let $g\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $||f-g||\le\epsilon$, then $||f_h-g_h||\le \epsilon$. By (uniform) continuity of $g$, we have that $||g-g_h||\rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$. claim follows by triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x)\sin(nx)\,dx=-\frac{1}{n}\cos (nx)f(x)|_{a}^{b}+\int_{a}^{b}{\frac{1}{n}\cos (nx)f'(x)}$ $$=-\frac{1}{n}\cos (nx)f(x)+\frac{1}{n^2}\sin(nx)f'(x)|_{a}^b-\int_{a}^b\frac{1}{n^2}\sin(nx)f''(x) dx$$ $$\cdots$$ Let us determine the value of the expression outside of the integration sign. Obviously $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{n}\cos (na)f(a)-\frac{1}{n}\cos (nb)f(b)=0}$ (as $n\to 0$). A similar calculation follows for the other expressions which are not integrands.

If the function $f(x)$ is $k$-differentiable, after $k$ steps, it will become a constant. If it it is infinitely differentiable, then too, it will be divided by a very huge power of $n$ in every step. As $n\to\infty$, after some point, all the terms in this representation will$\to 0$.

Comment: The function $f$ might not be differentiable at all.

Comment: @timhortons According to the OP $f \in C^1$